# Faster Method for R While Loop in least squares function

Tags: r

I'm trying to speed up the function below (for later bootstrapping) which performs least squares fitting of a straight line with errors in both x and y. I think the main hang up is in the while loop.  The input values for the function are the observations `x` and `y`  and the absolute uncertainties in those values `sx` and `sy`.

```
york <- function(x, y, sx, sy){

    x <- cbind(x)
    y <- cbind(y)

    # initial least squares regression estimation
    fit <- lm(y ~ x)
    a1 <- as.numeric(fit$coefficients[1])   # intercept
    b1 <- as.numeric(fit$coefficients[2])   # slope
    e1 <- cbind(as.numeric(fit$residuals))  # residuals
    theta.fit <- rbind(a1, b1)

    # constants
    rho.xy <- 0     # correlation between x and y

    # initialize york regression
    X <- cbind(1, x)
    a <- a1
    b <- b1
    tol <- 1e-15    # tolerance
    d <- tol
    i = 0

    # york regression
    while (d > tol || d == tol){
        i <- i + 1
        a2 <- a
        b2 <- b
        theta2 <- rbind(a2, b2)
        e <- y - X %*% theta2
        w <- 1 / sqrt((sy^2) + (b2^2 * sx^2) - (2 * b2 * sx * sy * rho.xy))
        W <- diag(w)
        theta <- solve(t(X) %*% (W %*% W) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% (W %*% W) %*% y

        a <- theta[1]
        b <- theta[2]

        mswd <- (t(e) %*% (W%*%W) %*% e)/(length(x) - 2)
        sfit <- sqrt(mswd)
        Vo <- solve(t(X) %*% (W %*% W) %*% X)
        dif <- b - b2
        d <- abs(dif)
        }

    # format results to data.frame
    th <- data.frame(a, b)
    names(th) <- c("intercept", "slope")
    ft <- data.frame(mswd, sfit)
    names(ft) <- c("mswd", "sfit")
    df <- data.frame(x, y, sx, sy, as.vector(e), diag(W))
    names(df) <- c("x", "y", "sx", "sy", "e", "W")

    # store output results
    list(coefficients = th,
        vcov = Vo,
        fit = ft,
        df = df)
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, how big are your vectors, and how long is the code taking to run?

Comment: Use  `crossprod(A,B) ` for  `t(A)%*%B`

Comment: Allocate memory for your results vector before the loop, and then avoid cbind and rbind.

Comment: This probably isn't a particularly satisfying answer, but this is precisely the sort of function where you should probably be doing that while loop in compiled code called from R.

Comment: In general there are 7 to 10 x-y pairs.  The code runs fine for a single dataset of that length, but then hangs if I try loop through more than 10 datasets.

Comment: That's not very much data to be running slowly. If it were me, I would probably do some careful debugging to see what's happening in the while loop that's taking so long. Particularly as regards to your tolerance setting and successive values of d.

Comment: Also try using R's built-in functions for doing the weighted regression instead of rolling your own; it may or may not be faster but is certainly more dependable. `theta <- coef(lsfit(x,y,wt=w^2))`

Comment: @SeanMulcahy There's a big difference between running slowly and hanging. Did you mean that for more than 10 datasets, the runtime increases dramatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function can be sped up with a few simple changes. Primarily, you should move anything out of the while loop that doesn't need to be there. For example, you run `solve` twice on the same data. Also, you calculate the `sfit` on every iteration, when you only use it on the last iteration of the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
york.fast <- function(x, y, sx, sy, tol=1e-15){
    # initial least squares regression estimation
    fit <- lm(y ~ x)
    theta <- fit$coefficients
    # initialize york regression
    X <- cbind(1, x)
    d <- tol
    # york regression
    while (d >= tol){
        b2 <- theta[2]
        # w <- 1 / sqrt((sy^2) + (b2^2 * sx^2) - (2 * b2 * sx * sy * rho.xy)) # rho.xy is always zero!
        w <- 1 / sqrt(sy^2 + (b2^2 * sx^2))  # rho.xy is always zero!
        # W <- diag(w)
        # w2 <- W %*% W
        w2 <- diag(w^2) # As suggested in the comments.
        base <- crossprod(X,w2)
        Vo <- solve(base %*% X)
        theta <- Vo %*% base %*% y
        d <- abs(theta[2] - b2)
     }
     e <- y - X %*% theta
     mswd <- (crossprod(e,w2) %*% e) / (length(x) - 2)
     sfit <- sqrt(mswd)

    # format results to data.frame
    th <- data.frame(intercept=theta[1], slope=theta[2])
    ft <- data.frame(mswd=mswd, sfit=sfit)
    df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, sx=sx, sy=sy, e=as.vector(e), W=diag(diag(w)))

    # store output results
    list(coefficients = th, vcov = Vo, fit = ft, df = df)
}
```

A little test:

```
n=225
set.seed(1)
x=rnorm(n)
y=rnorm(n)
sx=rnorm(n)
sy=rnorm(n)

system.time(test<-york.fast(x,y,sx,sy)) # 0.37 s
system.time(gold<-york(x,y,sx,sy)) # 1.28 s
```

I noticed that `rho.xy` is always fixed at zero. Is this perhaps a mistake?

I noticed as well that you often use `cbind` to convert a `vector` into a `matrix` with one column. All vectors are automatically considered matrices with one column, so you can avoid a lot of extra code.

As @joran mentioned, the tolerance level is set so small that it will take a long time to converge; consider using a larger tolerance.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I've obviously got some more to learn but these suggestions were extremely useful.

Comment: +1: I'd definitely prefer using existing routines for the fitting, though.  Still, here's an additional speedup when doing it this way: the crossproducts can be sped up by using regular multiplication instead of matrix multiplication because the second term is a diagonal matrix.  At the very least, `w2 <- diag(w^2)`, instead of `W%*%W`.